# How to add jar file on the remote server?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat

I want to add jar file on my remote server but i am unable to do it. Please tell me how to add jar files on the server and use them. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your remote server is probably accessible using FTP or ssh. Read the documentation of your remote server provider. That is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed the war file which contains the jar files that I have added while creating my project.Those jar files were added in the lib folder of WEBINF while creating the project.